# Numerically order list

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

The following code orders a list as follows: 1. item, 10. item, 100. item... What do I add or change to order the list numerically(1,2,3...)?

```
  function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
      if(typeof ul == "string")
        ul = document.getElementById(ul);

      var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("LI");
      var vals = [];

      for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
        vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

      vals.sort();

      if(sortDescending)
        vals.reverse();

      for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
        lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      var desc = false;
      document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
        sortUnorderedList("lister", desc);
        sortUnorderedList("bin", desc);
        desc = !desc;
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements of your set are stored as strings so they are ordered alphabetically. I believe your sort should work as expected if you add your elements as integers, using the parseInt function.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change:

```
vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);
```

To:

```
vals.push(+lis[i].innerHTML);
```

This will convert the `String` to a number and make the ordering work as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
vals.sort()
```

you should do:

```
vals.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

that will do the sort "for numbers".

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's a good practice to sort strings like strings and ints as ints.

So I suggest you to write various sort functions for data types that could apper in your project, and with regexp determine which function to use.

Also there is a great jQuery plugin, that could be easy extended: http://tablesorter.com/docs/